# Change the "Show All" button in a Wordpress Portfolio Filter

Tags: php, filters, templates

I'm working on a website for a client; https://www.lingvox.services/ and I'm trying to solve an issue on this page https://www.lingvox.services/mobila-la-comanda/

The client is Romanian, and wants the website to be completely Romanian as well, however I'm facing a problem with the portfolio. It's showing "Show All" as an option. However, the client wants to keep this button (in addition to the other filter buttons) but he wants it renamed to "Taote". I tried editing a file named template-portfolio.php, specifically this line:

`<a data-option-value="*" class="selected" href="#showall"><?php  esc_html_e('Show All','interiart');?></a>`

I tried editing the `esc_html_e('Show All','interiart')` to `esc_html_e('Taote','interiart')` but it doesnt work.

The picture below shows the filter buttons and the Show All button.
[image]

TIA

Comment: Before going any further: I am under the impression that you are directly translating the theme php files instead of using localization files (.po and .mo files), am I right? Another question: do you have experience with WordPress internationalization API and functions like [`esc_html_e`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_e/)

Comment: Perhaps read about how WP handles internationalization for some clues - https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/localization/